# how to find out a specific text from a long text in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a long text. how to get only "Brandshubs" from below HTML?

output = **Brandshubs**3.7

Comment: Do you want to only check if that exists in output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `re.search('Brandshubs', s)` or `findall` function in python `re` library.
But you will get the string `Brandshubs` always, that's not meaningful so I guess you want to check exists or count the times? For that you can check/count
the results of these functions' return directly

Answer (score 1):

You can use either [`text.find("Brandshubs")`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-find/) or utilize the Python [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) library if you need something more sophisticated.